# AssetManager list not Returning anything

Tags: android

The following code produces a list with no entries:

```
 AssetManager am = getContext().getAssets();
    try {
        String[] xmls = am.list("assets/images");
        //Do something...
    }
    catch(IOException e)
    {

    }
```

There are plenty of files in my assets/images directory. What's wrong here?

Answer (score 5):

Get rid of `assets/` from your `list()` call and see if that helps.