# Assets folder in Android Studio?

Tags: android, android-studio, typeface, custom-font

Im trying to use a custom font, and I've read that I suppose to place the fonts in assets/fonts. I'm using Android Studio and it doesn't seem like I have a assets folder. So I created one. But my app crashes when I place the assets folder in src/main. Im using this code to load my fonts.

```
Typeface fontRegular = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "fonts/DroidSans.ttf");
Typeface fontBold = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "fonts/DroidSans-Bold.ttf");

myDeviceModelTxt.setTypeface(fontRegular);
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I keep mine in Project/Module/src/main/assets/fonts

Comment: possible duplicate of [Where to place Assets folder in Android Studio](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18302603/where-to-place-assets-folder-in-android-studio)

Comment: See this http://stackoverflow.com/a/35865160/3496570

Answer (score 53, accepted):

I am not sure if there has been any bug fixes since this was asked, but I am using the current structure for a project in Android Studio 0.5.2:

```
root-module
|--.idea
|--app
|----build
|----src
|------main
|--------assets
|----------SomeFont.ttc
|----------AnotherFont.otf
|--------java
|----------source code here
|--------res
|------AndroidManifest.xml
|----build.gradle
```

And then obtain it by calling

```
Typeface.createFromAsset(mContext.getResources().getAssets(), "SomeFont.ttc");
```

Word of caution though, there is a bug (https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=9904) that prevents typefaces from being garbage collected properly. Use a singleton!

Answer (score 13):

Create Assets folder Right click on app->>new->>Folder->>AssetsFolder like below image

[image]

Put your font inside this folder by just copy and paste. and use below code for example..

```
Typeface tf = Typeface.createFromAsset(getContext().getAssets(), "YourFontName.ttf");
setTypeface(tf);
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply follow this path:

```
File > New > folder > assets Folder
```

Here App must be selected before creating folder.

For more information see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27673773/3073945)

Answer (score -1):

The assets folder should be placed under the root of the project.
See [here](https://xjaphx.wordpress.com/2011/10/02/store-and-use-files-in-assets/) for more examples.

Comment: Not according to this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18302603/where-to-place-assets-folder-in-android-studio

Comment: Weird. I need to check this stuff. Either Google enhanced the getAssets to search for both in the root and under src/main or the post you gave is missing something. I'll check and update.

Comment: @LiorOhana that post seems to refer to eclipse, not to Android Studio