# Android assets folder is empty

Tags: java, android, assets

I want to list folders and files in asset folder, but I find out i empty. I searched for the answer but it did not helped, on google, stackoverflow and many others.

I tried many approaches with AssetManager and only that gave some output was:

> getAssets().list("/");

But assets folder it listed was empty...

I run application from eclipse (device on usb). Can anyone tell me what I do wrong? I have feeling that assets folder I open is not form my application...

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Are you sure you have `/assets` folder in the project?

Comment: Yes I'm sure, and its not empty one.

Comment: I even added font in assets/font/font.tif and loaded it with TypeFace, but still assets folder was empty

Comment: Have you solved this somehow?

Answer (score 5):

I was using `getAssets().list("/");` and it returned a list of the files in the root of the app:

```
D/        (25498): Listing files in /
D/        (25498): AndroidManifest.xml
D/        (25498): META-INF
D/        (25498): assets
D/        (25498): classes.dex
D/        (25498): lib
D/        (25498): res
D/        (25498): resources.arsc
```

Then I tried listing `"/assets"` but it was always empty. Then I found out that a relative path is needed and `/` for the root folder can not be used.

`getAssets().list("");` lists the files in the root of the assets folder.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
AssetManager assetManager = appContext.getAssets();
String[] filelist = assetManager.list("");
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get the assets files like this:

```
try {
    Resources res = getResources();
    AssetManager am = res.getAssets();
    String fileList[] = am.list("/");
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: Yeah, I tried this too. All approaches with AssetManager that I found on google I tried.

Answer (score 0):

I see you were using Eclipse, I switched to Android Studio but had the same problem. Comparing many answers led me to this:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/33542563/524355

The asset folder is "next" to the res folder (in AS, there is even a wizard for it). I put it manually "into" the res folder that's why asset folder was gone/not compiled into the apk! If this is done by the build tools that you use in Eclipse (ADT) you might have suffered from the same situation.

[image: assets not inside but parallel to res folder]